# Integration test a manual transaction with transaction template

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-transactions

I am getting null pointer exceptions on my transaction template when I try to test my method that uses manual transactions. When I am running the application in Spring Boot it works as expected.

```
@Autowired
TransactionTemplate template;

public CompletableFuture<MyResultEntity> addToA(BInput input) {
    return CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(
            () -> template.execute(status -> {
              A a = aRepository.findOne(input.getA());
              List<B> addedBs = saveBs(input.getB(), a);
              return new MyResultEntity(a, addedBs);
            }), MyCustomExecutor());
}
```

I have tried using a mock template and inject it like this:

```
@Mock
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

@InjectMocks
private MyClass myClass;
```

I have also tried annotating my test with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

When debugging this configuration the template is actually injected and is not null any more. But since I am interested in testing the actions in the transactions I do not wish to mock it so i use:

```
when(transactionTemplate.execute(Mockito.any())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

This throws a new null pointer exception though since the transaction template tries to use the TransactionManager and that is still null.

How can I unit test my method calls inside the the transaction template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I normally do is not to call the real method, but to just mock the real behavior instead. Calling the real method in the mock will fail, because a mock is not managed inside of springs injection context. Well, to be exact, you can make them exist inside the injection context by adding them to a test configuration (plain SpringMVC) or using @MockBean (spring boot). But still they are just injected as a dependency. But won't receive any dependencies. For unit tests this is most often the desired behavior.

So just do something like:

```
when(_transactionTemplate.execute(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> invocation.<TransactionCallback<Boolean>>getArgument(0).doInTransaction(_transactionStatus));
```

_transactionStatus can be a mock itself to test the usage of the state inside the callback.

Mocking is what mocks are used for :)

Comment: If used TransactionCallbackWithoutResult with doInTransactionWithoutResult how to do, I tried, but has only doInTransaction method for getArgument(0)

Comment: @Many_question try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77350743/5509227

Answer (score 0):

If `TransactionManager`  is `null` it means that Spring probably didn't load all necessary dependencies in the test context.
Anyway, why mocking the `TransactionTemplate` if you need to invoke the `execute()` method ?
Your test looks like an integration/sociable test and not an unit test.
If it is the case, you don't need to mock anything.
If you want to write an unit test that tests the actual logic in the `addToA()` method, you should use mock without partial mocking.
Mock dependencies used in the Supplier provided and assert that the expected `MyResultEntity` instance is returned.

Note that your unit test will have a limited value and may be considered as brittle as it asserts only that a series of method was invoked.  Generally you want to assert a behavior in terms of more concrete logic such as  computation/extraction/transformation.

Here is an example (no tested but it should give an idea on the way) :

```
@Mock
Repository ARepositoryMock;

@Mock
Repository BRepositoryMock;

@Test
public void addToA() throws Exception {

    BInput input = new BInput();

    // record mock behaviors
    A aMockByRepository = Mockito.mock(A.class);
    List<B> listBMockByRepository = new arrayList<>();
    Mockito.when(ARepositoryMock.findOne(input.getA())).thenReturn(aMockByRepository);
    Mockito.when(BRepositoryMock.saveBs(input.getB(), aMockByRepository)).thenReturn(listBMockByRepository);

    // action
    CompletableFuture<MyResultEntity> future = myObjectUnderTest.addToA(input);
    //assertion
    MyResultEntity actualResultEntity = future.get();
    Assert.assertEquals(aMockByRepository, actualResultEntity.getA());
    Assert.assertEquals(listBMockByRepository, actualResultEntity.getListOfB());
}
```

Comment: It is an integration test. I'll have a look at the solution as soon as I can.