# Junit Unit Test For a Method That Includes TransactionTemplate

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have a method that includes transactionTemplate in it. My test works when I run debug mode but not when executed directly.

My test works when I run debug mode because I think transactional operation is done while working debug mode. But when I just run it works wrong. How can I overcome this problem?

This is my method:

```
@Override
public void saveAndUpdate(DataDictionaryDTO input) {
    try {
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                DataDictionaryEntity ent = null;
                if (NullUtils.isNotNullOrZero(input.getId())) {
                    ent = dataDictionaryRepository.findById(input.getId()).orElse(null);
                }
                dataDictionaryRepository.save(dataDictionaryDTOMapper.map(input, ent));
            }
        });
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        throw new UserFriendlyException("there.is.already.such.a.value");
    }
}
```

Comment: pls show us your test

Answer (score 0):

Try this mock code

```
when(transactionTemplate.execute(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        TransactionCallbackWithoutResult transactionCallbackWithoutResult = (TransactionCallbackWithoutResult)invocation.getArguments()[0];
        transactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(new SimpleTransactionStatus());
        return null;
    });
```